# How do you add a submodule as a reference to a repository?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I'm creating a project that needs to use some repositories. I have them all in a directory called "ThirdParty". The idea is for this previously mentioned directory to store links to the respective repositories.

For the time being I have all the third party repositories uploaded to the main project.

I would like this repositories cloned and in the main project. An example of this could be [OpenPose/3rdParty](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/tree/master/3rdparty)

Perhaps what I need is not a submodule. In the end I want the users to download manually the third party repositories to an empty directory if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Using submodules in this case makes a lot of sense. Couple notes:

To add a submodule, switch to the folder you would like the submodule to exist in and execute the following command:

`git submodule add https://[path-to-git-repo-for-the-submodule]`

The result will be a sub-folder being created that contains that complete repo.

You can use this command to clone your repo with all the submodules:

`git clone --recursive YOUR-GIT-REPO-URL`

Or if you have already cloned the project, you can use:

`git submodule init`

`git submodule update`

Comment: I think I didn't express myself correctly, the problem is that the submodules add the code 'per se' instead of referencing the repository. Problem can be found at https://github.com/RoberPlaza/NycaTechEngine/tree/master/ThirdParty/glfw

Comment: Ah... yes. I do know how that can be problematic. Git doesn't lend itself well to that solution. I have utilized a few techniques: Generally speaking, I commit the compiled binaries to the Git repo that uses them; this helps with version compatability. Alternatively you can commit the "official" binaries to the Submodule repo but cloning that repo will still result in the complete source code as well as the location of the binaries within that repo.